# Python dataframe interpolation - adding a new row to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a dataframe that I would like to add a new row when EVM = a specific value (-30) and update the other columns with linear interpolation.

```
Index    PwrOut      EVM       PwrGain    Vout

0    -0.760031   -58.322902  32.239969  134.331851

1   3.242575    -58.073389  32.242575   134.332376

2   7.246203    -57.138122  32.246203   134.343538

3   11.251078   -54.160870  32.251078   134.383609

4   15.257129   -48.624869  32.257129   134.487430

5   17.260618   -45.971596  32.260618   134.586753

6   18.263079   -44.319692  32.263079   134.656616

7   19.266674   -41.532695  32.266674   134.743599

8   20.271934   -37.546253  32.271934   134.849050

9   21.278990   -33.239208  32.278990   134.972439


10  22.286989   -29.221786  32.286989   135.111068

11  23.293533   -25.652448  32.293533   135.261357
```

For example, (in the 3rd column) EVM = -30 lies between rows 9 and 10 above. How can I include a new row (between rows 9 and 10) that has EVM = -30 and then update the other columns (in this new row only) with linear interpolation that is based on the EVM column's position between the numbers in rows 9 and 10?
It would be great to be able to search and find the rows that EVM =-30 lies between.
Is it possible to apply linear interpolation to some rows but nonlinear interpolation to other columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation is by far the easiest part. Here is one approach.

First, find the missing rows and add them one by one:

```
targets = (-50, -40, -30)  # Arbitrary
idxs = df.EVM.searchsorted(targets)  # Find the rows location
arr = df.values
for idx, target in zip(idxs, targets):
    arr = np.insert(arr, idx, [np.nan, target, np.nan, np.nan], axis=0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)
```

Then you can actually interpolate:

```
df2 = df1.interpolate('linear')
```

Output:

```
       PwrOut        EVM    PwrGain        Vout
0   -0.760031 -58.322902  32.239969  134.331851
1    3.242575 -58.073389  32.242575  134.332376
2    7.246203 -57.138122  32.246203  134.343538
3   11.251078 -54.160870  32.251078  134.383609
4   13.254103 -50.000000  32.254103  134.435519
5   15.257129 -48.624869  32.257129  134.487430
6   17.260618 -45.971596  32.260618  134.586753
7   18.263079 -44.319692  32.263079  134.656616
9   19.266674 -41.532695  32.266674  134.743599
8   19.769304 -40.000000  32.269304  134.796324
11  20.271934 -37.546253  32.271934  134.849050
12  21.278990 -33.239208  32.278990  134.972439
10  21.782989 -30.000000  32.282989  135.041753
13  22.286989 -29.221786  32.286989  135.111068
14  23.293533 -25.652448  32.293533  135.261357
```

If you want custom interpolation methods by columns, go individually, e.g:

```
df2.PwrOut = df1.PwrOut.interpolate('cubic')
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe! One thing I forgot to add is that the data is looped, so the EVM = -30 would appear many times in the dataframe. df.EVM.searchsorted(targets) appears to only work with EVM = -30 appears once in the dataframe. Is there an alternative function to use to identify the multiple row locations every time that EVM=-30? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understood you. If you pass -30 for example multiple times in the `targets`, it would work just fine. What do you mean by "everytime EVM == -30" if it does not appear in the DataFrame?

Comment: I found that I couldn't use the searchsorted function when the data is looped and the EVM data passed through -30 many times.. I slightly modified your code to use a for loop to search the length of the EVM column to find all the row indexes in which EVM passes through -30. Thanks again for your help, this appears to do the job nicely!

Comment: `targets = -30  # Arbitrary 
ind=0 
idxs=[] 
for ind in np.arange(0,len(df['EVM_dB'])-1):
     if df['EVM_dB'][ind] <targets and df['EVM_dB'][ind+1] >targets:
         idxs.append(ind)
          
arr = df.values 
i=1 
for idx in idxs:
     arr = np.insert(arr, idx+i, [np.nan, targets, np.nan, np.nan], axis=0)
     i+=1     
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)     
df1 = df.interpolate('linear')`